# Where to list Puerto Rico?

Tags: html, forms, states, countries

When listing countries and states in a form (be it in a webapp, an OS app, mobile app, etc.), where should Puerto Rico be listed. In the country list or the state list?

Puerto Rico is not a country but its not a state. Puerto Rico is a US territory and a common wealth and they use the US dollar.

[https://www.google.com/search?q=puerto+rico+state+or+country](https://www.google.com/search?q=puerto%20rico%20state%20or%20country)

So, should it be listed with the US states or as its own country or in some other way?

Comment: Do you have to include puerto rico in your list?

Comment: Yeah, its funny cause we had the app up for a long time and just now some one from puerto rico complained that there wasn't an option for puerto rico.

Comment: I originally had my explanation as to why I believe this is not off topic, however, another user edited my question removing the explanation. Here it is again: "I know at first this doesn't seem like a question for StackOverflow but I feel this is the best place because many programmers are faced with this decision. Please refute if you have a better place to post it, and I will gladly follow suit. But since there is no "political correctness for programmers" StackExchange site, I debate this is the best place for now."

Answer (score 1):

There is still a country code under ISO 3166.  So to answer your question, it depends on your app.

http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/iso-3166-1_decoding_table.htm

Answer (score 1):

According to the USPS, it goes with the States, and shows up as PR: [USPS Abbreviations](https://www.usps.com/send/official-abbreviations.htm)